# Published Android app not available on SGH-S730M

Tags: android, publish

I just uploaded my app on Google Play and it's visible on the Google Play Store, but it's incompatible with my Samsung SGH-S730M for some reason. In the list of available devices I see the Samsung SGH-S730G , but not mine. Any thoughts on how that could happen? My device has the Google Play store.

Comment: What minSdkVersion did you declare in your Manifest? What OS do you have on your device?

Comment: Can you post your manifest file here?

Comment: Hey all,

--Sorry I can't answer my own question--

minSdkVersion was 2.3 and my phone has 4.0.4, that was not the issue.

However, now, a few hours later, suddenly the app can be installed on my device (although still not visible in the list of available devices).

The problem might have been that I checked too fast after uploading? That's just a guess though.

Thanks for the quick replies.